# UITableview double delete button issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

We are using an uitableview and allow users to delete uitableviewcells, but a strange bug occurs, where two delete buttons appear.

[image: Delete bug]

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your help and time.

Regards
Jing Jing Tao

**UPDATE 1**

Code for my cell at index for row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
}

// Configure the cell...
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
//Sections logic
Model *info;
switch ([indexPath section])
{
    case 0:
        info = [self.bapiArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        break;

    case 1:
        info = [self.tablesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        break;

    case 2:
        info = [self.tcodesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

cell.textLabel.text = info.subsection;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = info.text;
if(!(info.program == (id)[NSNull null] || info.program.length == 0))
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Program:%@", info.text,info.program];
}

}
```

Comment: show code for you "cell for row at indexpath", it seems like the issue is due to dequeue cell .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've edited my message, if you need to see the code for my custom method 'configureCell', let me know, I can add that too

Comment: Show us `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. And you should use the modern way: Register cell with cellIdentifier and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:`.

Comment: I've updated the post again with details of the method. I will change it to the modern way and see if it fixes the issue.